# Does Conservation of Four-Momentum imply Conservation of Energy in Particle Physics?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, momentum, energy-conservation, conservation-laws

In Particle Physics processes, we always assume four-momentum conservation. Does this automatically lead to energy conservation, since the four-momentum conservation must be fulfilled for every component, hence also for the $0$th component, which is just energy (setting $c = 1$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

Nine more characters